# Index out of range (python if loop)

Tags: python, loops

Hi everyone and thanks for reading

I have to get up and running a piece of code I have not written, this is my first time in python. The code was working in a daily basis to extract some meteorological data we download every day. As there have been some changes in the original data I've had to adapt the code, basically changing some IDs to get new location of desired variables.

But now another problem has risen, in a loop I get this error message

```
('XXX', 19, 368, 124, 130)
('YYY', 19, 368, 0.0, 130, 2.49e+19, 0.25)
('XXX', 20, 382, 124, 130)
('YYY', 20, 382, 0.0, 130, 2.55e+19, 0.0)
('XXX', 21, 398, 124, 130)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/meteo/UVI/TREBALL/input-make-erythem.py", line 125, in <module>
    auxcm=float(lista[j][(auxcm+4):len(lista[j])])*28.9645*dens[i]/(6.023e17)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

`XXX` and `YYY` locate the output of print statements added in the code to look for the error . It seems that the problem comes when reading dens[i] for the 21st (and last) value in dens. But how can I check if the problem comes from `dens[i]` or `len(lista[j])`

I assume both `i` and `j` start from 0 and that the loop should end after `dens[i]` is completely read.

The piece of code where the problem appears (I suppose)

```
alt=[16,14,12,10,9,8,7,6,5,4.5,4,3.5,3,2.5,2,1.5,1,0.75,0.5,0.25,0.0]
#1/cm3
dens=3.460E+18,4.74E+18,6.48E+18,8.59E+18,9.71E+18,1.09E+19,1.23E+19,1.37E+19,1.55E+19,1.64E+19,1.73E+19,1.81E+19,1.93E+19,1.97E+19,2.00E+19,2.15E+19,2.30E+19,2.36E+19,2.42E+19,2.49E+19,2.55E+19]


print("lenlista",len(lista))
for j in range(len(lista)):
    auxcm=lista[j].find("CLWMR")

    if -1 != auxcm:
         auxcm=lista[j].find("val=")
         print("XXX",i, j, auxcm, len(lista[j]))
         auxcm=float(lista[j][(auxcm+4):len(lista[j])])*28.9645*dens[i]/(6.023e17)
         print("YYY",i, j, auxcm, len(lista[j]),dens[i],alt[i])
         cm.write("      "+str(alt[i])+"     ")
         cm.write(str(auxcm))
         cm.write("    10.0\n") #radio estandar de gota de nube en um (variacion de 2 um --> 5%)
         i=i+1
```

`len(lista) = 512`
alt and dens have 21 elements

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `print("XXX",i, j, auxcm, len(lista[j]))` show ?

It is likely that the value of `i` is the source of the problem.  If there are more than 21 entries in `lista` that can find "CLWMR", the increment of `i` will bust the `dens` list (i.e. `i` will be >= 21).

You could either ignore the extra "CLWMR" entries by adding `and i < len(dens)` to the condition or report it as an error by adding another if that  signals the issue and breaks the loop.

This could also mean that you need to add more entries to the dens/alt lists or that your data is flawed.

Comment: You are probably right, there are 23 values for CLWMR so I suppose I have to add two extra values to `dens` and `alt`

Comment: If you do that, I would suggest you also make sure that the order of the data (cloud mix ratio lines) matches the altitude and density values in your two lists. The extra entries are not necessarily going to be at the beginning or end. In fact, it could be a completely different stratification.  If the altitude is somewhere in the data, I would suggest using it to find the corresponding density in the lists rather than rely on ordering of input data.

Comment: Yes, I have to check altitude and density of model levels (in mb) and properly set the list of density values.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the call to `dens[i]` since at this moment `i` is 21 but `dens` has a length of 21 (unless I can’t count properly) thus the index is out of bounds, which is what the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: So, it should stop when i is 20. How can I force that?

Comment: Well it really depends on what exactly your code is trying to achieve. If whatever `i` is counting can disregard the 21st element (so if you are only counting for `dens`) then break the loop. It also depends how `i` is being used. Could you possibly share more code regarding this?

Comment: `i` is just being used to read dens, no more appearances in the code

Comment: Then you can just add the statement: `if i == 21: break` at the beginning of the for loop. However from the answer below it seems like it would be better for you to increase `dens` so that CLWMR can be covered.

You can also add the condition after the `i=i+1` or just before it as `if i == 20: break`